# Gutenberg update break admin editor page layout

Tags: wordpress, editor, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm currently experiencing an issue with Wordpress where sometimes when Gutenberg is enabled and I am editing an admin page the layout is all broken. To me, it looks like it missing a JS/CSS files but I can't find any JS or CSS files not being loaded correctly. Redownloading the core with WP-CLI fix the issue so that's why I'm assuming that it's related to Wordpress core and specifically with the new Gutenberg editor but then again, I don't see any difference in my git history that could point out on what the issue is. Is anyone else has ever experienced this issues and no exactly what is causing that?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What's shown in the console?

Comment: @KT.C nothing actually. There is no 404 or anything else

Comment: Looks like it's missing some files, does the network tab in the browser show anything? little difficult to debug.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in the network tabs that could lead me on why. But I have found that that it could be related to Wordfence because when I deactivate the plugin it seems to work and when I reactivate it, it breaks again. Not sure why though

Comment: If it's a new website, it might be worth resetting Wordfence, so it recreates all the default files.